# How to calculate numbers to arbitrarily high precision?

Tags: fortran, arbitrary-precision, rounding-error

I wrote a simple fortran program to compute Gauss's constant :

```
program main

implicit none

integer :: i, nit
double precision :: u0, v0, ut, vt

nit=60
u0=1.d0
v0=sqrt(2.d0)
print *,1.d0/u0,1.d0/v0

do i=1,nit
  ut=sqrt(u0*v0)
  vt=(u0+v0)/2.d0
  u0=ut
  v0=vt
  print *,1.d0/u0,1.d0/v0
enddo

end program main
```

Result is 0.83462684167407308 after 4 iterations. Anyway to have better results using the arithmetico-geometric mean method? How do people compute many digits for numbers such as pi, Euler's constant, and so on ? Does each irrational number has a specific algorithm?

Comment: In Fortran what I do is use Mathematica to evaluate these constants to however many digits I need/want, then cut and paste those digits into the definition of a parameter in my source files.  Seriously, computing these numbers accurately to high-precision is a difficult task.  If you really want to do it yourself, start reading here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Comment: According to your link, memory is the main limitation and fortran is not adapted to such computations. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This page -- http://myweb.lmu.edu/dmsmith/FMLIB.html -- suggests that you have drawn an inaccurate conclusion from the Wikipedia article.  Google will help you find more libraries to study.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you goal is to insert a constant value into your program, the easiest solution is to look up the value on the web in or a book.   Be sure to add a type specification to the numeric value, other Fortran will treat it as the default of single precision.   One could write pi as `pi_quad = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288_real128` -- showing the use of a type specifier on a constant.

If you want to do high precision calculations, you could some high precision type available in your compiler. Many compilers now have quadruple precision.  If they have the Fortran 2008 version of the ISO_FORTRAN_ENV module, you can request this via the type `real128`.

Arbitrary precision (user specified number of digits, to very high number of digits) is  outside the language and is available in libraries, e.g., MPFUN90, http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/

Yes, different constants have various algorithms.  This is a very large topic.

Answer (score -3):

Solution for pi:

```
  pi = 4.0d0 * datan(1.0d0)
```

Comment: -1 Apart for being a very minimal and low quality answer, it is also wrong. The OP is asking about arbitrarily high precision, not double precision.